# How do I setblock whatever item is currently in hand in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing minecraft, doing some random stuff in my server.

I was creating an automatic builder, to avoid having to build blocks, so that I could just walk, and it would build.

What I did was create a pulse-clock connected to a commandblock having:

`execute @p ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ dirt`

I was wondering how I would make that "dirt" into whatever item I was holding in hand, or at a specific slot in my inventory as  `setblock ~ ~ ~ {slot:0b}`  doesn't seem to work.

--

On another note, how can I make the commandblock to work inside a range, and/or coordinates, as in  `execute @p[x=~10,y=~,z=~15,r=5] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're asking is impractical at best.  You would need one command block for every block type, at the very minimum.

Comment: What I'm asking for is to make the game read what you have in your inventory, instead of putting a statick block like dirt. Is there any way around it?
 (And can I read a trigger (scoreboard) to activate and deactivate the setblock, using a comparator+repeater?)

Comment: No, I'm telling you that can't be done.  At least not currently.  As for the second question in your comment, ask a new question about that.

Comment: Would other methods of selecting the block (rather than having it selected in your hotbar) be good enough for your purpose?

Comment: That's a good idea, hadn't thought about it. But the whole idea was to "build faster in creative mode". I guess I could maybe use the ID of a dummy-score, executing a command. (I wish /powertool was added to vanilla minecraft, I really hate all these long commands ... and for users it would be great (Yeah, I know, add a command block, but it's not the same. xD))

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible unless you want to add command blocks for every block type.

Comment: I said "impossible unless".  Also, besides time, it would contribute a significant amount of lag.

Comment: Put that in your post :) Use the [edit] button.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a command blocks comparator setup for each block, which is already a pain to do for just one item. To have the command block work inside of a range, use the fill command instead, ex

```
/fill ~1 ~-1 ~1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 dirt
```

will give a 3x3 area of dirt beneath you.